# Palindrome Index Hackerrank with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I submitted the following codes for the Palindrome Index challenge on HackerRank, but it fails some test cases with the error Exceeded time limit. I am not sure what is wrong with my codes.

Basically, I implement a distinct "helper" function to check if a string is a palindrome. In the `PalindromeIndex` function, I first check if a string is a palidrome then return `-1`, else I will loop through the string, try to remove each letter to see if the remaining string is a palindrome.

If it is, return the *index* right there; else, continue.

If the loop finishes without returning any index, that means there is no result, I return `-1`.

That is what I am trying to do, but I cannot find out the problem here. Thanks!

```
function isPalindrome(s) {
      for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (s[i] !== s[s.length - 1 - i]) {
                  return false;
            }
      }
      return true;
}


function palindromeIndex(s) {
      let result = isPalindrome(s);
      if (result) {
            return -1;
      }
      else {
            for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                  let newS = s.slice(0,i) + s.slice(i+1);
                  if (isPalindrome(newS)) {
                        return i;
                  }
            }
            return -1
      }
}
```

Comment: It's correct, but it's too slow. They want you to find a better algorithm, so they put in some test cases that won't finish in a reasonable time using a naïve algorithm.

Comment: So how can I improve my algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You need to optimize your palindrome function. Just run loop from `0` to half of array.

```
function isPalindrome(s) {
      for (let i = 0; i < s.length/2; i++) {
            if (s[i] !== s[s.length - 1 - i]) {
                  return false;
            }
      }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: I changed it to loop from 0 to s.length/2 but it still doesn't work, same error. Also, I think in terms of complexity analysis, n and 1/2 * n are the same, so I don't think that is the problem? Do you have any other idea? :(

Comment: @ChrisLe Can you give link to problem so I can try something out myself?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem

Comment: @ChrisLe You probably need a different algorithm which is used `O(N)` instead of O(N ^ 2)

Comment: I think the problem is with O(N^2) too, but have no idea how to reduce the complexity down to O(N) :(

Answer (score 0):

> ...else I will loop through the string, try to remove each letter to
> see if the remaining string is a palindrome

This is the problem. It isn't necessary to loop through the whole string again, because as soon as a pair of letters is found in the string which break the palindrome - the answer must be either the index of the first letter or the second letter of the pair OR - if the removal of both letters don't produce a palindrome - then return `-1`.

```js
function palindromeIndex(s) {
  function isPalindrome(s) {
      for(let i=0; i< Math.floor(s.length/2);i++) {
          if(s[i] !== s[s.length-1-i]) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
  for(let i=0; i< Math.floor(s.length/2); i++) {
      if(s[i] !== s[s.length-1-i]) {
          if(isPalindrome(s.slice(i, s.length-i-1))) {
            return s.length-i-1;  
          } else if(isPalindrome(s.slice(i+1,s.length-i))) {
            return i;  
          } else {
              return -1;
          }
      }
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(palindromeIndex('aabaa'))
console.log(palindromeIndex('aaab'))
console.log(palindromeIndex('baaa'))
console.log(palindromeIndex('baaabcc'))
```

This solution will have a time complexity of O(n) because only one loop is necessary

Comment: It does work now! I finally understand your solution! Thank you so much @Danield

Answer (score 0):

I will just draw up the basic idea, because I guess you want to try for yourself:

```
aaa = -1   
aaab = 3   
baaa = 0   
bbaa = -1

You only want to loop through the string once.

You only need to loop through half the string, and do comparisons.
```

I would just focus on moving indexes.

String: `baaa`

**Default variables:**
*position*: -1
*startNudge*: 0
*endNudge*: 0

At index i (start at 0):

- check `i` + *startNudge* against `string.length - 1 - i` + *endNudge*.
- If not equal:

  - check index `i + 1` + *startNudge* against `string.length - 1 - i` + *endNudge*.

    - if equal, set *position* to `i` and set *startNudge* to 1.
  - else, check `i` + *startNudge* against `string.length - 2 - i` + *endNudge*.

    - if equal, set *position* to `string.length - 1 - i` and set *endNudge* to -1.
  - else break loop by returning -1.
  - if position already saved, break loop by returning -1.
- continue loop.

Return *position* if loop completes.